# Print a single byte as hex in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I open a binary file with Python3 and want to print byte-by-byte in hex.
However, all online resource only mention printing a "byte array" in hex.

Please tell me how to print only 1 single byte, thanks.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("./datasets/data.bin", 'rb') as file:
        byte = file.read(1)
        while byte:
            print(byte) # how to print hex instead of ascii?
            byte = file.read(1)
```

Comment: Did you mean: `print(hex(byte))`?

Comment: `print(hex(byte[0]))`. `hex()` takes either an `int` object or the object has to define an `__index__` method that returns an `int`. Indexing into a `bytearray` or `bytes` object returns an `int`.

Comment: @quamrana interpreter complains: TypeError: hex() argument can't be converted to hex

Comment: @Axe319 interpreter complains: TypeError: hex() argument can't be converted to hex

Comment: @Qiao Placing `print(byte)` immediately before the `hex` line, what does it print? Do you have a sample of `data.bin`?

Comment: @Axe319 It's binary byte, and I know the 1st byte of the file is 0xD3, it's not displayable on screen as ascii character. The file can be downloaded here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fm8bfxjg7olm0b0/data.bin?dl=0

Comment: @Qiao it works for me.. What about `print(byte[0])` before the `print(hex(byte[0]))`. That should print an integer value.

Comment: @Axe319 Thanks. It's really weird that I use 'python test.py' will failed, while just 'test.py' could work. Do you know what's the difference?

Comment: If you are concerned about that, please ask a brand new question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```py
print(hex(byte[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an `f-string` like this just prints two hex digits for each byte:

```py
print(f'{byte[0]:02x}')
```